# Exception Error Errorno 10061 in solrpy program

Tags: python-2.7, solr

I just started working on solrpy with below code.

```
import solr

# create a connection to a solr server
s = solr.SolrConnection('http://localhost:8083/solr')

# add a document to the index
s.add(id=1, title='Lucene in Action', author=['Erik Hatcher', 'Otis Gospodnetic'])
s.commit()

# do a search
response = s.query('title:lucene')
for hit in response.results:
    print hit['title']
```

it is throwing Socket error: Errno 10061. Can anyone please help me in resolving this issue.

Answer (score 1):

TCP Error 10061 means `No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it`. So you have to check the program can connect `localhost:8083`. Checking your **Jetty** or other web container (ex. **tomcat**).